# Hibernate mapping a map <enum, Integer>

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, annotations

i am using Hibernate and JPA annotations to map my classes. I am having a problem when hibernate trys to map this class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_item")
public class SocialItem extends Item {

    private SocialSlot slot;
    private Map<SocialStat, Integer> stats = new HashMap<SocialStat, Integer>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public SocialSlot getSlot() {
        return slot;
    }

    public void setSlot(SocialSlot slot) {
        this.slot = slot;
    }

    @MapKeyClass(value = SocialStat.class)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Integer.class)
    public Map<SocialStat, Integer> getStats() {
        return stats;
    }

    public void setStats(Map<SocialStat, Integer> stats) {
        this.stats = stats;
    }

}
```

My socialStat class is:

```
@Embeddable
public enum SocialStat {
    HAPPINESS

}
```

And i am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: social_item, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(stats)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass.validate(UnionSubclass.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1108)
```

I am guessing this happens because i am trying to map to a basic Class, but shouldnt the @ElementCollection annotation solve that?

My item class is like this:

```
package com.cabesoft.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

import com.cabesoft.domain.utils.Money;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Item {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Integer requiredLevel;

    private Money price;

    public Item() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "oid")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Column(name = "required_level", nullable = false)
    public Integer getRequiredLevel() {
        return requiredLevel;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setRequiredLevel(Integer requiredLevel) {
        this.requiredLevel = requiredLevel;
    }

    @Embedded
    public Money getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Money price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the @Embeddable annotation from the enum and tell us if it goes better.

Comment: Nop , that didnt work, got the same error

Comment: Also remove the @MapKeyClass annotation and the targetClass attribute of ElementCollection. And add a MapKeyEnumerated annotation to specify if the key of the map must be stored as a string or as an ordinal.

Comment: I did as you said my classes ended like this:
 
@ElementCollection
 @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 public Map<SocialStat, Integer> getStats() {
  return stats;
 }

and my social stat class: public enum SocialStat {
 HAPPINESS

}
 and still got the same error

Comment: And? Did it solve the problem?

Comment: No, it did not. Still getting the same error

Comment: Show us the code of Item. I think I know what the problem is, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't confirm my idea, and I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Because correct mapping has been tried, it looks obvious that `@ElementCollection` annotation is not consumed. `@ElementCollection` was introduced with JPA 2.

JPA 2 API is present, implementation is likely still missing. Older Hibernate versions are not JPA 2 implementations. If 3.X is preferred, then latest one (3.6.10) is worth of trying.

If updating Hibernate version is not an option, then [@CollectionOfElements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html) can be used.